# Must compile twice in Xcode before seeing changes

Tags: xcode, compilation

I have to build my projects twice in xcode before seeing changes. This has to be the most annoying thing I have encountered so far. In two completely different projects, after adding the FacebookSDK and integration, changes I make don't seem to compile the first time. However, if I build twice, the changes can be seen upon the second build. Anyone experienced similar issues or know anything I can change to fix this?

Comment: Did you restart your computer?

Comment: Yes, this is ongoing for about a month now...

Comment: Strange issue. I'd suggest a reinstall.

Comment: Well this occurred on two different computers and two different apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about make clean and then build?

Comment: I know how to clean and build, this is not the issue